# Bind apps to VPN network interface with group based routing policies

Tags: networking, mac, vpn, routing, pf

My goal is to bind some applications to a specific network interface (tun0). I believe my best option would be that of creating special routing rules for applications launched with a specific group (sudo -g $groupname $app-path).

Assuming OS X supports user group based routing policy (pf should, right?), can anyone provide an example of such a rule?

The ultimate goal is that of using my current VPN connection only for some apps while routing main traffic to the default network interface (en0). I’m aware that a ssh tunnel would be a saner approach, but unfortunately my VPN provider does not support ssh.

Thank you in advance for your help. If successful I will publish a clear and concise guide to help any other user with my needs.